# Rails Auto FIll similar fields used in sign up and new profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My sign up page takes `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, and `account_type` as input from a user. When the same user creates his profile page, how can I automatically fill up the the form so that the fields for `:first_name` etc. are already filled up and saves time?

Schema.rb

```
 create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.date     "birthday"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "account_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
    t.string   "handedness"
    t.string   "coach"
    t.date     "date_joined"
    t.integer  "year"
    t.string   "course"
    t.string   "main_weapon"
    t.string   "additional_weapon"
    t.integer  "cellphone_number"
    t.integer  "emergency_contact"
    t.string   "contact_name"
    t.string   "contact_rel"
    t.string   "player_status"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "account_type"
    t.string   "security_key"
  end
```

_form view:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@profile) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">

    <%= f.input :first_name %>

    <%= f.input :last_name %>

    <%= f.input :username %>

    <%= f.input :gender, :collection => ['Male', 'Female'] %>

    <%= f.input :birthday %>

    <%= f.input :email %>

    <%= f.input :account_type %>

    <%= f.input :year %>

    <%= f.input :course %>

    <%= f.input :cellphone_number %>

    <%= f.input :handedness, :collection => ['Right','Left','Both']%>

    <%= f.input :coach %>

    <%= f.input :player_status, :collection => ['Active','Retired'] %>

    <%= f.input :main_weapon, :collection => ['Foil','Epee','Saber'] %>

    <%= f.input :additional_weapon, :collection => ['Foil','Epee','Saber'] %>

    <%= f.input :emergency_contact %>

    <%= f.input :contact_name %>

    <%= f.input :contact_rel %>





  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You would need to use cookies: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.0/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html if you want the form to include those values on load, or you can use a controller to pull from the model and insert it into the form.

Comment: My first question would be: why are you duplicating column names? Is it possible for a user to have multiple profiles (one-to-many relationship)?

Comment: no I have a `has_one :profile` in my user model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have in `ProfilesController` a `new` method. Just initialise the fields at that point and they'll pre-fill the form fields for you.

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
    @profile.first_name = current_user.first_name
    @profile.last_name = current_user.last_name
    @profile.account_type = current_user.account_type
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Something odd happened. The solution worked but only the email field was pre-filled. The rest are blank

Comment: Hm... don't see why the first_name would be blank.  Are you sure the first_name is being stored in the user record?  If you do `rails c` from a terminal window, you can look at user records (e.g. `u = User.last`) and make sure the values are there. (`u.first_name`)

Comment: Checked the user. It seems it didn't store the other values. How could I fix this?

Comment: Ok, are you using `devise` or did you write your own user login?

Comment: If it's your own, make sure that your `user_params` method has the fields whitelisted... that it includes `:first_name, :last_name` etc.

Comment: I'm using devise

Comment: Right, check this out, it should help... http://jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html